# Multi-processed file reading in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, software-design

I want a file to be read in a multi-processed way. Each process will be a class instance doing some specific task, but the class where the file is being opened will be a singleton class.

We don't want to batch the entire file into a number of processes instead we want each process to asynchronously read a batch of lines from the text file where no two processes will have the same line.

I know this is quite a task to execute and I have tried multiple ways to achieve this task but was unsuccessful.

Below is the code snippet where I tried to achieve the above mentioned

```
class ListFromTextFile():

    def __init__(self, config: str):

        self.file_pointer = open(file_path, "r")
        self.batch_size = config["batch_size"]

        self.__lock = Lock()
        self.__lock_aquire = False
        

    def get_list_of_pids(self):

        function_name = "get_list_of_pids"

        pids = []

        try:

            for line in self.file_pointer:

                if self.__lock_aquire:
                    pid = line.strip("\n")
                    pids.append(pid)

                else:
                    self.__lock.acquire()
                    log_message(function_name, "Lock aquired !!!")
                    self.__lock_aquire = True

                if len(pids) == self.batch_size:

                    self.__lock.release()
                    log_message(function_name, "Lock released !!!")
                    self.__lock_aquire = False
                    
                    yield pids
                    pids = []

            if len(pids):

                self.__lock.release()
                log_message(function_name, "Lock released !!!")

                yield pids

        except Exception as e:
            err = str(e)
            trace_back = traceback.format_exc()

            log_exception()(self.function_name, err, trace_back)
```

Here ListFromTextFile is a singleton class and, processes will call get_list_of_pids() which will yield a list of pids. The task here is every batch generated and yielded by all processes must be unique.

Any suggestions to improve the above code or new ideas are welcome.

Comment: If I understand your problem, you want to create a ProcessClass (each instance will be a process) that can process a number of line of one particular file. The singleton is here to give a number of line that was not read yet ?
If true, there is many issue with your code:
1. Your class is not a singleton, 2 instantiation of the class will give two instances. 
2. Shared variable are not as easy in Thread when working with Process 
3. You should replace your boolean 'lock_acquire' by a Semaphore

Comment: Hey, @AdrienDerouene thanks for pointing out the issues in my code. Let me explain it more clearly.

So basically the input text file has ids. A class has been defined which has a method that will query mongo for the list of ids and then do some processing on it. So all processes spawned will be an instance of the class mentioned earlier.

And I am initializing ListFromTextFile class only once and that very instance is used by all processes.

Can you further explain why ListFromTextFile class won't be a singleton? Also why a semaphore would help instead of a boolean?

Comment: each process you create will have its own version of `ListFromTextFile` instance in its own memory, that's how multiprocessing works, look into python multiprocessing shared objects.

Comment: In Python, if you want to implement a Singleton you have to overload  the special class method __new__ and use a class attribut or going throw metaclasses (there is a lots of example on internet). But your task is more complicated and Singleton will not work because, as @AhmedAEK already said it, process will have it's own space memory because it will launch a new Python interpreter (class attribut are not shared in this case). You will have to read more about Manager or Queue in order to make it work (and Semaphore will not be usefull then because Queue and Manager already gets it) .

Comment: just use multiprocessing.Queue to post your data to each worker process, and read your file from a single process.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not necessarily a singleton but rather a class instance that can be sharable among multiple processes. The most straightforward way I know of doing this (other people might have other ideas) is to create a *managed* class from `ListTextFile`. I would first modify its definition so that method `get_list_of_pids` is not a generator function (these cannot be pickled). Instead you can just call it repeatedly to return the next batch of *pids* until an empty list is returned signifying end of file on the input file. As a managed object running within a manager's process and method calls are handled by threads, it is sufficent to to run `get_list_of_pids` as a critical section using a `thread.Lock`.

For demo purposes my input file, *test.txt*, consists of 7 lines:

```None
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

**The Demo**

```Python
from threading import Lock
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

file_path = 'test.txt'

class ListFromTextFile():

    def __init__(self, config: dict):

        self.file_pointer = open(file_path, "r")
        self.batch_size = config["batch_size"]
        self.eof = False
        self.__lock = Lock()


    def get_list_of_pids(self):

        function_name = "get_list_of_pids"

        pids = []
        if self.eof:
            # Returning an empty list signifies end of file:
            return pids;

        with self.__lock:
            while True:
                line = self.file_pointer.readline()

                if line == '':
                    self.eof = True
                    # Return what we have if anything.
                    return pids

                pids.append(line.strip('\n'))
                if len(pids) == self.batch_size:
                    return pids

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

def worker(reader):
    import time

    while True:
        pids = reader.get_list_of_pids()
        if not pids:
            # Empty list returned -> end of file
            return
        print(f'Current pid: {current_process().pid}, pids: {pids}', flush=True)
        time.sleep(.2) # Give other process a chance to run

def demo():
    MyManager.register('ListFromTextFile', ListFromTextFile)
    with MyManager() as manager:
        config = {'batch_size': 3}
        reader = manager.ListFromTextFile(config)
        p1 = Process(target=worker, args=(reader,))
        p2 = Process(target=worker, args=(reader,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()
```

Prints:

```None
Current pid: 1492, pids: ['1', '2', '3']
Current pid: 29072, pids: ['4', '5', '6']
Current pid: 1492, pids: ['7']
```

**But Is There an Alternate Approach?**

If each process does the processing for a single batch and then terminates (those details have not been provided), the main process can be doing all the batching and providing each batch to a multiprocessing pool:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process

file_path = 'test.txt'

def create_batch(config):
        batch_size = config["batch_size"]

        pids = []
        with open(file_path, "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                pids.append(line.strip('\n'))
                if len(pids) == batch_size:
                    yield pids
                    pids = []
            if pids:
                yield pids

def worker(pids):
    import time

    print(f'Current pid: {current_process().pid}, pids: {pids}', flush=True)
    time.sleep(.2) # Give other process a chance to run

def demo():
    pool = Pool(2)
    # lazily evaluate the iterable using imap_unordered
    # as a memory-savings technique. Specify a chunksize if
    # the number of batches are huge:
    config = {'batch_size': 3}
    pool.imap_unordered(worker, create_batch(config))
    # Wait for all tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()
```

Prints:

```None
Current pid: 4316, pids: ['1', '2', '3']
Current pid: 13424, pids: ['4', '5', '6']
Current pid: 4316, pids: ['7']
```